# How to bind toolbar buttons on MVVM Pattern?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

How can I bind a collection of Commands in viewmodel to a toolbar in related view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an ItemsControl in your view and overwrite the ItemTemplate and ItemsPanel to make it look like a ToolBar